# What are the benefits of updating Android Studio mid-project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently running Android Studio 2.3.3 and noticed 3.0 came out not too long ago. I was wondering what precautions should I take if I wanted to update Android Studio mid development of an app?   Will I have to make any changes to my manifests or anything? Should I just wait until I release my project then update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering what precautions should I take if I wanted to update Android Studio mid development of an app?

Before updating to 3.0 just take a backup of your project. Nothing more precautions you want.

> Will I have to make any changes to my manifests or anything?

Not exactly before the update to 3.0. After the update, open your project in new android studio. Then new android studio 3.0 will prompt you about the new gradle plugin and dependency changes. You need to allow the changes android studio want (it'll automatically do it, but some manual configurations like 3rd party library updates are also needed if you are using them).
There may be some errors will occur during the build process, don't panic. It's due to the new gradle plugin. You may find answers for that error (if any) in SO.

> Should I just wait until I release my project then update?

That's upto you. You can update at any time you want.

And please take a look at the official release notes of [android studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to know the new changes and [features](https://developer.android.com/studio/features.html). There is a whole bundle of it.
By the way I'm using 3.0, cheers. Happy coding.

Comment: Hey thanks man! I appreciate it!

Comment: Most welcome. Happy coding pal